# Wrap external http url into https

Tags: http, ssl, https, proxy

I have url of some external service I need to integrate our legacy system with.
Our legacy system is using some sort of bridges (pre-defined connectors) to talk with external world.
And currently there is only web connector for https. But that external service is available only through http, i.e. no SSL on that end and we can not do anything about it.
So I'm wondering maybe there is some online service, which could wrap http url into https, some sort of public proxy or whatever, so I could get https url in a few clicks.
For now it's just a proof of concept project, so I'm trying to avoid installing any internal proxy in our network etc. Need just the simplest and the quickest solution, which would give me https url.

Thanks in advance for you help, guys.